# Configuring a Trigger on an Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, configuration

My end goal is to create a triggered mailing in ExactTarget that fires when a user submits a Web2Lead form generated from Salesforce. Our integration between the too services (ET and SF) is in place and I am at the point of configuring the CampaignMember object for triggers.

I'm trying to use the steps on this [ET documentation page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/triggered_sends/) to set it up in my Sandbox org, but it won't allow me to save the trigger because it returns a compile error: variable does not exist: et4ae5.triggerUtility

Salesforce support says ExactTarget needs to give me the correct variable, but I'm tired of waiting (getting the run-around) and this is rather urgent. Is anyone familiar with this issue and/or does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thanks! I'm a new admin so still learning!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error can occur if attempting to setup the Apex Trigger (outline in Step 1 on the link provide) without having the latest version of the package installed.

Find the package version by going to Setup > Installed Packages, Find the entry for Marketing Cloud.  If it shows something less than 5.41 then follow the link on this page to get the latest package:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_v5_install_guide/v5_package_installation/